# Can't pass a function value to set an array size C++

Tags: c++

This is my function;

```
int charCount(ifstream &file)
{
    char character = ' ';
    int count=0;
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        file.get(character);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This is the main;

```
int listSize = charCount(file);
char *arrayList = new char [listSize];

int index = 0;
while (!file.eof() && index < listSize)
{
    file.get(arrayList[index]);
    index++;
}
```

When i try to print this array, nothing shows up. But when i set an integer value like this `char *arrayList = new char [50];` it works.
How can i solve this ? Thanks.

### EDIT:

I solved it by calling `clear()` and `seekg()`

charCount function now looks like this

```
    int charCount(ifstream &file)
{
    char character = ' ';
    int count=0;
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        file.get(character);
        count++;
    }
    file.clear();
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: That's not [what `eof()` means](http://tinyurl.com/fuck-eof).

Comment: You've already reached the end of file once. Guess what's going to happen if you try to go further...

Comment: You may want to search your platform API for any *file memory mapping* functions.  Conceptually, the OS treats the file as memory and handles the reading and writing for you.

Comment: Also, if you are going to read the entire file into memory, consider using the `ifstream::read` function rather than reading character by character.  See also: `seekg(0, ios::end);` and `tellg()` to determine the file size.  This way you don't have to read every character to determine the size.  There is also a technique of using OS functions to get file sizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not allocation of the array.  The problem is you read the whole file to find out its size, so it is already at eof when you try to read it again to get its contents.

Answer (score 1):

when you will execute this function `charCount(file);` .You will reach to end of file already .In that case below loop will never **execute** .

```
while (!file.eof() && index < listSize)
{
    file.get(arrayList[index]);
    index++;
}
```

For the same reason , you didn't get anything inside array .